# Selenium RC: Running browser on another X11 desktop

Tags: desktop, x11, selenium-rc

I'd like not to be disturbed by the browser that is launched by Selenium RC. Is there any way how to force it to run the browser on another X11 desktop? Running Selenuim server on another desktop does not solve the problem.

Vít Šesták 'v6ak'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the DISPLAY environment variable to a different display than the one your desktop is using.  This must be set when starting up the Selenium server.  Selenium will then use this value when starting up the browsers.

Comment: Thank you, but you probably didn't understand me well. I've one display and four desktops. I can switch them by Win+F1/F2/F3/F4. $DISPLAY does not seem to be able to affect the desktop which the app is opened on.
I've discovered that OpenBox (WM that I use) can set a specific desktop for specified windows. Window is identified by Name/Class/Role/type (eg. main/psi//normal). But I don't know how to make the Selenium Firefox windows specific.

Comment: No worries.  I understood, but adding another display would likely be the simplest thing for you.  I doubt you're going to find too many people trying to achieve what you are.

Comment: Hmm, but I'm not sure that I can map a display to a desktop.

Comment: Well, it is not a bad idea at all. At first, I've to run a new session:

$ xinit /usr/bin/openbox-session -- :1

So, I've two sessions and I can switch them by Ctrl+Alt+F7 and Ctrl+Alt+F8. I can see that these session have different $DISPLAY. So, I can use this solution now. It is probably better than the other.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, on Linux you can start for example Xvfb (X in a virtual framebuffer) to provide an X environment and launch the selenium controlled browser in that.

We are doing that for years on headless server boxes and that work just fine (well from time to time you have to shoot a hanging browser, but that is the same on a desktop).

First install Xvfb:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then start selenium server in background via xvfb:

```
xvfb-run java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
```

Finally run your tests as usual (`phpunit`, or whatever you are using).

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be good. However, I'd prefer to run in another desktop, not in virtual screen. It is sometimes useful to watch the progress and maybe analyse the problem.

Comment: You can use Xvncserver instead. We found it to be not reliable enough. You can run a lightweight desktop like xfce and let it start a vncserver and selenium rc

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using workspaces/viewports not X using devilspie.

This addon lets you put a custom title on firefox, I installed it on my selenium profile:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/57/

I replaced Mozilla Firefox in the titlebar with FFSELENIUM

Then use devilspie to pin those windows to firefox:

http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/07/25/how-to-set-default-workspace-size-and-window-effects-in-gnome/ http://foosel.org/linux/devilspie

Then create a file .devilspie/selenium.ds with the contents:

(if
    (and
        (contains (window_name) "FFSELENIUM")
    )
    (begin
        (set_viewport 3)
    )
)

Woot firefox windows in the third viewport!